# how to catch that server is unable in burp extension?

Tags: java, burp

I'm developing a burp extension.
I'm using callbacks.makeHttpRequest(host, port, bool, request) method.
When burp can reach server everything is OK, but if server is unable if throws errors to stderr.

here is code

```
protected static final String HOST = "127.0.0.1";
protected static final int PORT = 1337;
private IBurpExtenderCallbacks callbacks;

private class MyThread implements Runnable {

    private IHttpRequestResponse request;

    MyThread(IHttpRequestResponse inputRequest) {
        request = inputRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String host = "http://" + HOST + ":" + PORT + "/";
        host = host + "?" + "host=" + request.getHttpService().getHost() + "&port=" +
                request.getHttpService().getPort();
        try {
            URL url = new URL(host);
            byte[] hostrequest = helpers.buildHttpRequest(url);
            try {
                byte[] response = callbacks.makeHttpRequest(HOST, PORT, false, hostrequest);
                if (response != null) {
                    IResponseInfo responseinfo = helpers.analyzeResponse(response);
                    if (responseinfo.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                        callbacks.makeHttpRequest(HOST, PORT, false, request.getRequest());
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                stdout.println("Server is unable");
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            stdout.println("URL CREATING ERROR");
        }
    }
}
```

So if HOST is unable,             byte[] response = callbacks.makeHttpRequest(HOST, PORT, false, hostrequest);
 throws error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Request has not yet been issued
   at burp.cfc.makeHttpRequest(Unknown Source)
   at burp.BurpExtender$MyThread.run(BurpExtender.java:77)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I need to catch it by myself

Comment: please share the complete code with details to what HOST, PORT, callbacks datatypes you are using and what are they initialized to.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fPehemPf

Comment: i doubt the `host` -> `url` -> `hostrequest` generation code. The host seems not be correct to me.

Comment: Everything is ok, if server is reachable, i send request, server accepts it, request is correct. I just have a problem if i switch server off. I want my code just to print "server unreachable" to stdout, not to throw error to stderror